# Marshalling struct from C to C# - string field cut off?

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling

I am trying to marshal this C struct into C#:

```
#define NameSize 255

struct NamesList
{
    unsigned long Size;     // Number of <NameSize>-chunks in Names
    char* Names;            // will contain Size * <NameSize> characters!
};
```

This is my struct in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct NamesList
{
    public uint Size;     // Number of <NameSize>-chunks in Names
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string Names;            // will contain Size * <NameSize> characters!
};
```

I'm passing the NamesList struct as a reference to the following C function:

```
int getNamelists(unsigned long Handle, NamesList* nameLists);
```

Here's my PInvoke signature in C#:

```
    [DllImport("remote.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int getNamelists(
        uint handle, ref NamesList jNames);
```

The function works fine when only one name exists. However, if there are 2+ names, the Names field never contains any names past the first one. The Names field is always equal to the first name, even if 3 names exist (in which case, the Size is correctly assigned to 3)

I've been trying a bunch of different things but I can't get anything to work. What could be causing an issue like this? I tried setting the Names field's SizeConst to multiples of 255 based on what the size was, but that didn't work either. Any help is appreciated!

edit: Trying to marshal into a char[] instead of a string but having some issues with this code

```
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct NamesList
    {
         public uint Size;     // Number of <NameSize>-chunks in Names
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 255)]
         public char[] Names;            // will contain Size * <NameSize> characters!
    };
```

edit 2:

I solved my problem by using this struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct NamesList
    {
        public uint Size;     // Number of <NameSize>-chunks in Names
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public IntPtr Names;            // will contain Size * <NameSize> characters!
    };
```

Then I converted the IntPtr to a byte[] that was 255 * Size using Marshal.Copy, then used an Encoding.GetString call to turn that byte[] into a string that contained all 3 names.

Comment: What do you mean by other names? There is only one `Names`. Are you confusing characters in a string with multiple strings?

Comment: To be clear, the Names field is supposed to contain multiple names if they exist. And even when there are 2 or 3 different names, the Names field only contains the name of the first one.

Comment: How do you know that `Names` contains multiple names?

Comment: char* Names;            // will contain Size * <NameSize> characters!            I'm basing it off this comment and common sense. I am making an assumption, but it would make no sense if the Names field didn't contain multiple names

Comment: By definition, `LPStr` will stop at the first null characters because that is what terminates it. If the null character should not terminate it, you should declare it as something else on the C# side, e.g. a char array.

Comment: How you are delimiting your names?

Comment: @GSerg may be on to something. Lots of Win32 functions return multiple strings in a single buffer as `string1\0string2\0\0`

Comment: @EdPlunkett I guess OP concatenates strings in his code and assign to "names"

Comment: My guess is that there is a common delimiter for the names but I don't know for sure since I've never been able to see more than one name. I don't have the actual C code, just a DLL  .... giving the char array a shot

Comment: If it it is a double-\0 terminated list of \0-terminated strings, note that Size is probably the array count NOT the buffer length that is needed to hold them all.  If yes, you have to figure out the buffer length yourself.

Comment: The buffer length is 255 * the size, that didn't seem to help me when I set the char[] SizeConst to 255 or any multiples of it

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the C function's contract. Please provide the documentation.

Comment: Think of it as a BYTE array (binary array).  To convert it to an array of strings you need to copy out each string that ends in \0 .  Like desalinizing a set of strings from a file.

Comment: As a byte array, only the first 4 indexes have a non-zero value in them. They are 199, 233, 13, and 1

Comment: After assigning the Names value to an IntPtr, then converting that IntPtr to a byte array, then converting that byte array to a string, I was able to see all 3 Names. There are a bunch of /0s in the string but still, I can work with this! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great. Now you have a memory leak. Seriously, if you want help, we need to see the contract. Post the documentation for the C function you are calling.

Comment: Here's all the C documentation I have on the function: int getNamelists(unsigned long Handle, NamesList* nameLists);        This was included in the post, what else do you want

Comment: That's not documentation, that's a function prototype. The function documentation explains the contract it implements, e.g. the data layout on successful return, possible error conditions, ownership of the returned data/responsibility for cleanup, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I wasn't sure what you meant. Unfortunately none of that exists, I'll shoot them an email and see if they can put something together for me. And what do you mean, now I have a memory leak?